# AKS randomly change deployments and pods

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am investigating a robust way to scan my Azure AKS clusters and randomly change the numbers of pods, allocated resources, throttling and if possible limit connections to other resources (E.g. database, queues, cache).

The idea is to have this running against any environment (test, QA, live)

- Log what changes where made and when
- Email that the script has run
- Return environment to desired state

My questions are:

Is there tooling for this already?

If this possible via CRON/ Azure pipelines?

This is part of my stress development work cycle that includes API integration and load testing to help find weakness and feedback ways we can improve our offering and teams reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google "Kubernetes chaos engineering".

Look at Azure Chaos Studio https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/chaos-studio/#overview

Create a chaos experiment that uses a Chaos Mesh fault to kill AKS pods with the Azure portal https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/chaos-studio/chaos-studio-tutorial-aks-portal

Comment: Thanks for that, "Kubernetes chaos engineering" is a new term for me

Comment: No prob. Your question will likely be closed because you're asking for some kind of recommendation, this is out of topic on S.O.